# Data handling performance

Tags: vb.net

I'm not sure how to best handle the data I am working with so I wanted to ask what you guys suggested. I'm no expert so please try to be as simple as possible.

I'm writing an IRC bot that maintains a massive list of users(hundreds of thousands). It gives each user points based on the time they spend in IRC. So the data I must manage will consist of a user & their points.

I already tried storing the users in individual text files but that was a bad idea mostly due to wasting clusters on the HDD. Now I'm considering storing all the users in a single file but I'm concerned with the efficiency of processing through all the users.

Should I load the whole file into an array or just load the users that are online?

I hope you can understand what I am asking. I will try to clarify if needed.

Comment: This site is more for specific programming questions where you have some code that you can't make work rather than asking general what-should-I-use questions. Is there a reason you cannot use a database?

Comment: for hundreds of thousands, I would use a database.  Maybe only loading the rows related to the users in the chanel currently

Comment: What about just managing a few thousand? How would you do it if you didnt want to force users to install an sql or mysql database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this program is calling for the information to be stored in a SQL style database.  This load is beyond what I'd want to put into a single text file but can easily be handled in a database

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. I have never worked with a database so I was just using what I knew. Is it something that is practical for distribution to other users? Don't want to ask people to install a personal SQL server to use my bot.

Comment: @JoshLs looking into using MySQL then.  It's a lighter weight DB implementation

Comment: What would be wrong with using an Access database?
Just trying to keep from forcing users to install addition stuff.

Comment: @JoshLs nothing that I can think of.  I think it's a bit more mainstream these days to use MySQL but Access would probably be good enough for this